# What's the best expression to determine whether a specific flag is set

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I'm using this code to determine whether a specific flag is set.
Is there any short expression (without repeating `someFlag.flag1` twice)?

```
[Flag]
enum someFlag
{
    flag1 = 0x0,
    flag2 = 0x2,
    flag3 = 0x4
}

if ((someFlag & someFlag.flag1) == someFlag.flag1)
```

If there isn't then, I would create an extension method. Any idea?

Comment: what type is flag1 and someFlag?

Comment: @Tony The Tiger: enum, sorry, I'll edit my question

Comment: I am not sure, if there is any..

Comment: @@Tony The Tiger: Done, edited

Comment: `flag1` should probably be `0x1`, not `0x0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using .NET4 then you can use the built-in [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method.

```
if (yourValue.HasFlag(someFlag.flag1)) DoSomething();
```

In earlier versions of the framework then what you've already got is fine (I think that's exactly what `HasFlag` does behind the scenes).

Comment: Yes, I'm using .Net4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/), you can get the benefits of [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) without requiring .NET 4, with added type safety, and without boxing :)

```
if (foo.HasAll(SomeFlag.Flag1))
```

(There are `HasAny` and `HasAll` methods, as the argument you pass can contain *multiple* flags to match.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ((someFlag & someFlag.flag1) != 0)
```

Also, you shouldn't have flag1 = 0 - it needs to be 0x01, otherwise flags won't work.

Comment: Can cause problems if you use weird overlapping bit values (although that would probably indicate deeper design issues).

Comment: @LukeH: Yeah, all flag values should represent a single bit set (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.)

Comment: Of course, since the default value for all enum types is 0, it makes sense for 0 to be a valid member of the enum, even if it's something as simple as `None`.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, completely agree. I was referring to flag values you want to test for having been set.